# GitLab API: pipeline not returning all jobs

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm using the GitLab api, to list out the jobs in a pipeline.  It's always been fine in the past, but I've added a couple of extra items to the flow and now it doesn't return all of the jobs:

```
$ curl --globoff -sSH "$CURL_HEADER" https://.../api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$PIPEID/jobs?scope[]=success | jq --raw-output '.[] | "\(.id)"' | wc -l
20
```

The jobs that are missing aren't retries (as [noted here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/206908)).

I can see the missing jobids in the web interface.

Is there a maximum of 20 jobs via this method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So turns out this API response is paginated, there's no indication in docs for [this item](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs).

There is a general item describing [this here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/#pagination), but it doesn't give a list of routes it is related to.  If it did it would probably show up in a search far easier.

All I needed to do was append `&per_page=100` (qq-ing for the `&` for my use case).  Alternatively you can check the return header for the `X-Next-Page` value and then append `&page=X` to get the subsequent pages...

Related page variables are:

```
x-next-page: 2
x-page: 1
x-per-page: 20
x-prev-page: 
x-total: 23
x-total-pages: 2
```